# Stop changing width when I change position

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, animation

I have a problem with my CSS code. If I change the position to absolute, the width of my buttons changes. Of course, I have googled a lot and I found some articles about it but none of them works for me.

What I want to do:
I want to change the background of my application (the whole body background) and it should work like a layer above all the other elements. And that's the first problem. In order to use the z-index have to set a position. I can't set the background of the body itself because then no element inside the body can have a higher z-index than the body itself (or have I done something wrong and that works?).

But anyway: All the articles I found say, that I have to change the position of the parent element to the relative --> If I use the body tag there is no parent element and if I set the position of a parent div to relative the animation in the child div doesn't work anymore.

Do you know anything to solve this problem?

HTML:

```
<ion-content [ngClass]="{'background':flase }" padding>
    <div [ngClass]="{'containerDiv':true, 'fade':toFade}">
        <p class="question">{{question}}</p>
        <div *ngFor="let choice of choices">
            <button #thisElement [ngClass]="{'showAsTrue':(showResult && thisElement.value==choices[answer]?true:false), 'choice':true, 'buttonInBackground':buttonInBackground}" (click)="onClick(thisElement)">{{choice}}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button *ngIf="buttonInBackground" [ngClass]="{'goOnButton':true}" (click)="nextChoice()">Weiter</button>
</ion-content>
```

relevant CSS:

```
.fade {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
z-index: 1;
animation: toFade 2s 1;
animation-delay: 2.5s;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.goOnButton {
    background-color: green;
    width: 50%;
    color: white;
    font-size: 17pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 4pt;
    padding-top: 3%;
    padding-bottom: 3%;
    z-index: 2;
    animation: showButton 6.5s 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    position: fixed;
    top: 70%;
    left: 25%;
  }
@keyframes toFade {
from {
    background: rgb(254, 251, 182)
}
to {
    background: #2e2e2e;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
}
```

Information:
The ion-content is like the body.
For all who don't know angular2: [ngClass] binds a class when the boolean after the name is true. It is working perfectly, just the CSS isn't perfect.

Comment: Please edit your post and add some relevant code to explain your problem.

Comment: And a fiddle if possible

Comment: Did you try to give width to your buttons using css property?

Comment: I added the relevant code!

Comment: @JjavaEvgen I gave the buttons a width, yes

Answer (score 0):

You have many things going on in your code so I removed all that is not necessary and changed the body background as requested.

```
// src/app.module.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>App</h1>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="question">
        <p>Do you know how to play gitar?</p>
        <button>Yes</button>
        <button>No</button>
      </div>
      <button>Next</button>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [`
    .container {
      background-color: #eee;
    }
  `]
})
export class App { }

// style.css
body {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/QH4nla3WApmctLpZ6r8X?p=preview)